# M-* interpreted as M-8

Tags: gtags

I use gtags. I do `M-.` to go to the function definition, but then when doing `M-*` to go back to where I was nothing happen and the minibuffer shows as if I did `M-8` . My configuration is [here](https://github.com/kamomil/emacs-c-ide-demo)

Comment: Are you working in terminal emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Found what what it was, I have two languages installed. By default language is changed with `alt+shift`, this coincide with emacs's `M-*`

To set language change to use only `left alt+left shift` in xubuntu I did `settings --> keyboard --> layout` then set it in "Change layout option"